# Unable to use generic Subscriptions in workbench for testing Platform event

Tags: integration, platform-event, workbench

I have an Outbound platform event whenever there is a Contact record being created in Salesforce . I have a trigger which will write the data into the Platform event
I wanted to test in through workbench Streaming Push Topics
But getting the below error
[image]

I have given the API Enabled permission for the user's Profile
and also checked Enable Streaming API in User Interface.
Still the issue persists.
Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to User Interface in Setup and enable Streaming API and REST API. Thats what fixed it for me.